# Jquery multiply data in textbox array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've try but It work only first row . I want to add second row multiple quantity_box and unit_price then display in price without changing

```
$('.a,.b').keyup(function(){
  var textValue1 =$(this).parent().find('.a').val();
  var textValue2 = $(this).parent().find('.b').val();

  $(this).parent().find('.price').val(textValue1 * textValue2); 
});

hereis my new html


<td id="quantity" class="col-md-1">
    <input type="text"  name="quantity_box[0]" class="form-control a" />
</td>
<td class="col-md-1">
    <input type="text"  name="unit_price[]" class="form-control b" /> </td>
<td class="col-md-1">
    <input type="text" name="price[0]" id="price" class="form-control price" autofocus="" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working for the second row, beacause the `id` attribute should be unique, that's mean you can't have two `input`s with `id="a"` or `id="b"` or `id="price"`. Instead you can use the `class` attribute, so every `id` should be turned to a class, just like this:

```js
$('.a,.b').keyup(function(){
  var textValue1 =$(this).parent().find('.a').val();
  var textValue2 = $(this).parent().find('.b').val();

  $(this).parent().find('.price').val(textValue1 * textValue2); 
  var sum = 0;
  $(".price").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });

   $("#total").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text"  name="quantity_box[0]" class="form-control a" />
    <input type="text"  name="unit_price[]" class="form-control b" /> display in
    <input type="text" name="price[] "  class="form-control price" autofocus=" " />
      </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>  <td>
    <input type="text " name="quantity_box[]" class=" form-control a">
    <input type="text "  name="unit_price[] " class="form-control b"> display in
    <input type="text " name="price[] "  class="form-control price" autofocus=" ">
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<label> Toal:   <input type="text " id="total" class="form-control " autofocus=" "></label>
```

Comment: well if my second row id +1 how  can I loop i udated my html

Comment: thank you sir  I dont want to change id= price because I already finish function by using $("input[id *= 'price']")

Comment: Please don't teach wrong practices. Use `<td>` element inside `<tr>`, not `<div>`.

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi sir i updated my question I try to add new class name a,b,price  but it didnt work ( in my code) first I console log textValue1 textValue2 It print correct output  I think problem is in  $(this).parent().find('.price').val(textValue1 * textValue2);  not sure should i remove id="price"?

Comment: @test1321 try to see if your **HTML** code is the same as mine

Comment: well finally i find it out that's because i use 1 td each input 
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>

Comment: @test1321 Not necesserly you can do this `<tr>
  <td> YOUR INPUTS </tr></td>`

Comment: thank you now i change it already but Can I ask if sometimes I've to use `<tr><td> INPUT </td><td> INPUT </td><tr>` where shloud i've to change

Answer (score -1):

First of all, a few things must be fixed in your code.

You should not use the exact same `id` on multiple elements. `id` attributes are supposed to be unique for the entire page. That's why it only works for the first set of inputs. Use classes instead.

Also, the inputs return text values. You don't want to use them as is. You should use `parseFloat()` and/or `parseInt()` to convert them to numbers, and you also want to *validate* the input (make sure it's actually a number, rather than a text, like 'abc').

Finally, you need to wrap your inputs in `<td>` or it will fail to render correctly in some cases.

There are few more things that should be cleaned up (inconsistent whitespace in your attributes), but I won't go into that now.

Now on to the solution.

Now in this case, you want to handle the click event on a set of inputs, and then you want to figure out the multiple. You can do this by binding the event listener to the table element. You should use the `input` event instead of `keyup` because not all changes from inputs come from key events (e.g., if I paste a value into the input using mouse, it won't be caught by `keyup`).

In the event handler, you want to traverse the DOM tree up to the input's parent, and from then get a set of inputs you want to work on.

Putting most of what's discussed together you get code that may look like this:

```
$('#mytable').on('input', function (event) {
  var elem = $(event.target); // <-- this is the <input> element

  // From the input element, go up one level to the <tr> element
  var parent = elem.parent();

  // Find all the elements we'll be using using the 'name' attribute
  var qtty = parent.find('input[name="quantity_box[]"]');
  var uprice = parent.find('input[name="unit_price[]"]');
  var price = parent.find('input[name="price[]"]');

  // Leaving validation out for brevity, update the price
  price.val(parseFloat(qtty.val()) * parseFloat(uprice.val())); 
});

<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="quantity_box[]" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" name="unit_price[]" class="form-control" /> display in
    <input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control " autofocus=" " />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="text " name="quantity_box[]" class=" form-control ">
    <input type="text " name="unit_price[] " class="form-control "> display in
    <input type="text " name="price[]" class="form-control " autofocus=" ">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As I said in the comments, I've left the validation out for brevity so you'll sometimes see `NaN` in the output. Once the validation is in place, you'll see the correct output.

Here's a fiddle with the working code:

https://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/nowcfrbo/

Comment: @test1321 I've added a link to the working example code in a fiddle, so you can play with it and change it according to what you need.

Comment: In find('input[name="price[]"]');  is their anyway that find by class ? for example class="form-control price "

Comment: You can find by class if you add a class to the inputs, of course.

Comment: thank you sir  when i console log price it's always return false is that normally

Comment: When and where do you log it?

Comment: nothing I just want to know output var qtty so I try to log It return bolean right ?

Comment: It you are doing `console.log(qtty)` it should return a jQuery object.

Comment: Oh isee thnank sir