# jquery loop through html element array and calculate values in 3rd element input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input form where the user can dynamically add more input fields when pressing a button. What I want to do with jquery is to update all of the total_cost[] fields whenever I have a .keyup event on the respective replaced_part_qty[] or replaced_part_price[]

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-1">
    <label>Part price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="replaced_part_price[]" id="replaced_part_price">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-1">
    <label>Part Qty</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="replaced_part_qty[]" id="replaced_part_qty">
    </div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-1">
    <label>Total cost</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total_cost[]" id="total_cost" readonly>
</div>
```

I made a .click event on the new entry button since I didn't get it to work properly on the .keyup event.The problem with the event on the .add_more_lines button is that the user needs to add a new line when he wants to see the total cost for the previous line and in addition if I change something on a previous line then the values will not get updated because the code memorizes only the values from the last line.

The ideal situation would be that whenever the user changes the price or quantity on a line, it will recalculate the total_cost for that line.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

window.z = 0;   
        $('.add_more_button').click(function(){
         $('input[name="replaced_part_qty[]"]').each(function() {
             window.product_quantity = $(this).val();
         });
         $('input[name="replaced_part_price[]"]').each(function() {
             window.product_price = $(this).val();
         });

         $('input[name="total_cost[]"]').each(function() { 
            $('input[name="total_cost[]"]').eq(window.z).val(window.product_quantity*window.product_price);
         });
         window.z++;
     });
});
```

Comment: so when you say add a new line you mean add a new row? which includes the total part and quantity inputs , you should creata a minimal example to correctly describe your problem, because if you are adding new rows you must include the add new row script

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam, I have found a fix eventually using the answers from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854666/jquery-multiply-data-in-textbox-array . Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer in this post : [Jquery multiply data in textbox array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854666/jquery-multiply-data-in-textbox-array) and adapted it to work with dinamically added fields

Code below:

```
<div id="container1">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-md add_more_button" id="add_form_field">New Line &nbsp; <span>+ </span></button>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label>Price</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control a" name="pret_piesa_inlocuita[]">
        <label>Qty</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control b" name="cantitate_piesa_inlocuita[]">
        <label>Piece Price</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control price" name="cost_piese[]" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

New Line jQuery:

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ 

var wrapper = $("#container1"); 

        $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group col-xs-3">\
        <label>Price</label>\
            <input type="number" class="form-control a" name="pret_piesa_inlocuita[]">\
        <label>Qty</label>\
            <input type="number" class="form-control b" name="cantitate_piesa_inlocuita[]">\
        <label>Piece Price</label>\
            <input type="number" class="form-control price" name="cost_piese[]" readonly>\
        </div>');
    }
});
```

Calculate fields function:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.a,.b', function() {
    var textValue1 = $(this).parent().find('.a').val();
    var textValue2 = $(this).parent().find('.b').val();
$(this).parent().find('.price').val(textValue1 * textValue2); 
    var sum = 0;
$('.price').each(function() {
   sum += +$(this).val();
   });
});
```